# SortedList which allows duplicate values

Tags: c#, .net, collections, sortedlist

I need a list which enables sorted insertion while allowing duplicate sort values.

SortedList as well as SortedSet from the System.Collections.Generic namespace for example do not allow duplicate values.

The next thing is, that Remove should use a different value as the Sorting uses, which means, if I have a list of persons I want to remove them by their name but the list must be sorted always by age, so I always can find the oldest person with o(1) complexity.

I tried to achieve this by inserting in a normal List using BinarySearch. That works but the removal of values then is still o(n) which is too slow for me.

Comment: You should look for a database solution if you handle that much data.

Comment: The person thing was just for better understanding. Iam working on a pathfinding algorithm where "x,y" is the removal key and "distance" is the sort key. The number of items are a few hundreds but the method is called hundreds of times/second. Sure there are other possible optimisations for my problem but that would be another question.

Comment: .Net does not have heap (which is what you are asking for) - so you need to either implement one yourself or find library that provides one.

Comment: I take it you meant the `Delete` and not the `Add`.

Comment: You could allow duplicate values by wrapping e.g. `SortedList` and storing a collection as the value, or a value and counter record. Then add and subtract the counter. I am not sure that removing an item from `SortedList` isn't O(n), however. Coincidentally, I was just looking for a similar collection for a different SO question. If you just have a few hundred, throw memory at the problem - index with a `Hash<T>` on removal key returning sort key.

Comment: Can the x.y removal key have duplicates?

Comment: @NetMage: no, (x,y) ist unique.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Does heaps provide o(1) removal by a different key than the sorting value?

Comment: @codymanix Binary heap is O(logn) delete O(n) search. Maybe you can hold unique keys in `Dictionary<(x,y), int>` which ints refer to index in an array. You need to sync and ignore deleted values between those  but it should be fast.

Comment: @Berkays I think the issue there is deletion from the array would be order `n` or (potentially) unlimited growth. I think a `Dictionary` and a sorted `LinkedList` might work.

Comment: @NetMage He wouldn't actually delete it but ignore the index. This might pose another issues if he constantly replaces data though.

Comment: Perhaps you should list what performance requirements are desired? For example, is O(n) for add acceptable (e.g. `SortedList`)?

Comment: Add/Remove as well as the finding of the Minimum value should be no more than Log(n).